ARM STM32 Keil. #ifndef FILE_H, #ifndef _FILE_H_, #ifndef __FILE_H__ or #ifndef FILE_H_?
I'm working in the Keil IDE and make programs for STM32 microcontrollers.
Should I use:
    #ifndef FILE_H

    #ifndef _FILE_H_

    #ifndef __FILE_H__

or
    #ifndef FILE_H_

On the Internet I found these two variants. Which one should I use?

As for the duplicated question, the options 2 and 3 may not be used. The rest options are opinion-based.

Only the third is correct.

@john Why is that?

There's also #pragma once.

@HolyBlackCat Question seems to have been edited since I wrote that (or I was blind). Anyway the dupe answers the question.
